# Removing (or disabling) Music app in macOS

Tags: itunes, catalina, macos, music.app

How can I "hard remove" or somehow disable the "Music" app from macOS Catalina+?

I assume I need to boot disable SIP or similar which I'm fine with, I'm not just sure how to find the location of this app as it doesn't appear as `/Applications/Music` in the terminal.

Comment: The Music app is located in `/System/Applications/Music.app`, but I would strongly recommend against removing it. You could hide it instead using `sudo chflags hidden /System/Applications/Music.app`. This command will only work if SIP is disabled.

Comment: @jaume Why do you recommend against removing it? I'm in agreement but am curious to what your provision is. Ultimately I was going to move it to a backup drive or similar, like I did in Mojave.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, I would recommend against removing **anything** within `/System`. You don't really know the consequences. For instance, updates may fail. Or Apple may refuse to provide support. I'm not saying it is going to happen, it may be safe to remove the Music app or Apple may be obliging, but SIP is for me synonymous with "no user serviceable". Are you willing to take the risk? I'm not, but  of course, it's your choice.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get `Operation not permitted` even with `su` or as `root`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you just need prevent Music app or iTunes to launch, you could use noTunes: https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes

I didn't manage to find any better to disable it.

Comment: Epic solution considering no-trace removal option. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Music has never launched unless I specifically action it.

Comment: Nice. Works as advertised, homebrew install, and minimal nuisance. Even its icon can be hidden. Great stuff, thank you.

Comment: Every single time I adjusted my earbuds or scratched my ear apple music used to fly open and ask me to buy a subscription.  Now i can safely touch my ears in peace.

Comment: Could some sue Apple for this for anti trust violation for monopoly and unfair competition? There is no way to disable/uninstall Apple Music to prevent it from opening annoyingly. Apple also rejects your App updates if it has the word "Android" in it.

Comment: Kinda annoying that you need to install 3rd party software to prevent the non-removable apple software from opening. Reminds me of the days when windows PCs used to come pre-bundled with a bunch of bloatware.

Comment: This works nicely on Apple M1 Pro MacBook with macOS Ventura. I see the Apple Music icon pop up when I touch my earbuds, and before it reaches its place in dock and opens like it used to, it's squashed and kicked down, disappearing into the abyss of software that no one wants to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to soft-disable it, you can also Sign out (**account > sign out**) which will prevent the app from playing music or using any functionality that exists in the music app. Without an apple music subscription or being signed in the app looks like this - it's still possible to browse songs but they cannot be played or downloaded.

[image]

Comment: It still opens sometimes if you're not signed in. Just happened to me: rebooted computer, hit play on my headphones (with Spotify running) and the Music app intercepted the action and opened up.

Comment: @jcollum

what version of osx are you on?

Comment: 14, but it happened in 13 too

Comment: Interesting, I'm still running 12.X.X / have been since posting this so that might be the difference.

Comment: It opens when I double-click a wav file. Despite me repeatedly picking QuickTime as the "Always Open With" app.